# Receive data in batches?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

I've run into a problem where my WebAPI server is taking too long to respond because of the amount of database queries it has to make.

I would like to know if there is a way to return the data in batches. For example, the server could send a response to the client every time it has made 10 queries with the data it has fetched so far.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? If so, how? I had trouble finding anything about this on google. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-streaming-API

Comment: @LouFranco Can this be used with asp.net WebAPI?

Comment: No idea -- mostly I'm just trying to give you help on what to search for.